# Resume song in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have created a media player . I run the application properly. But I want to resume my song when I restart my activity. Why does my audio restart when I restart my activity?

How can I do this? I don't understand. Can any one help me??

Here is my code.

```
public class Audio_Activity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.audio);
    init();

    mp=MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.ennamo_yadho);
    Log.e("Song is playing","in  Mediya Player ");

    if(mp!=null) {
      length=mp.getCurrentPosition();
      Log.e("Current ","Position -> " + length);

      if(length > 0){
        mp.seekTo(length);
        mp.start();
        btnChapter.setEnabled(false);
      }
  }

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
        System.out.println("Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent this you should use a service for playing sounds while your activity goes to background. Refer to the android's documentation about the life-cycle of an activity to see what actually happens: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
mp.start();
mp.seekTo(length);
```

Referring to [documentation of MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> public void **start ()**
>   Starts or resumes playback. If playback had previously been paused, playback will continue from where it was paused. **If playback had been stopped, or never started before, playback will start at the beginning.**

Answer (score 0):

Save the mp.getCurrentPosition in a persistence of some sort, sharedprefs for instance in onPause, call pause() on the mediaplayer.

In onResume, do mp.start(), mp.seekTo(savedPosition).

Comment: Yes , I've tried already this way but nothing is resume .It will restart when activity is restart.

Comment: First follow the advice given by Gholamreza, you must do this in a Service. There is no way around it. As to the advice given by Johnny Sorensen, follow it as well, but only after following the advice by Gholamreza, and note that onResume() in this case means the onResume() of the UI thread, and that you must remove the code starting the Service from the onCreate()

Comment: @tazeen, And if you're still getting stuck, please post the modified code in your question. The answers you have been given by the others are fundamentally correct. The only way we can help you now is if you post your modified code.

Comment: Thanks for your response and cooperate . I have solved problem myself using shared preference.

Comment: a service is only necessary id he wants the audio to play in the background, and as far as I understood his problem, he just wants the audio to pause when the activity goes in to the background hence my suggestion