# How to stop activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have created an activity which includes media player in it.When I start activity, the music begins to play.But when the song is complete and when i click on back button on the emulator, it displays an error of (`IllegellStateException`).

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            
    setContentView(R.layout.audio);
    init();
    imgVw.setImageResource(R.raw.teddy_two);
    
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.ennamo_yadho);
    Log.e("Song is playing","in  Mediya Player ");
    Log.e("Current ","Position -> " + length);
    mp.setLooping(false);
    mp.start();
    btnChapter.setEnabled(false);
            
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!");
        }
    });
            
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
         
        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
         
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences. Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();
                
        int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        prefsEdit.putInt("mediaPosition", position);
        prefsEdit.commit();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("Activity is Resume !!!");
        int position = prefs.getInt("mediaPosition", 0);
        mp.seekTo(position);
        mp.start();
    }
        
    #Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
        { 
            if(mp!= null)
            {
                mp.pause();
            }
            //finish();
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

}

Comment: None of these answers good enough? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522185/how-to-resume-my-audio-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545166/how-to-resume-activity-with-audio-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524681/resume-song-in-android

Answer (score 4):

Use `finish();` in Activity class to stop Activity and return.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
MediaPlayer player;


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service started", 100).show();
    if(player.isPlaying())
        player.stop();

    else
        player.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mp!= null)
{

   mp.pause();
}
```

The above code snippet inside `if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))` seems to be the problem. You should check whether the player is playing or not. If it is playing then only pause should be called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();//should be onPause and not onStop

   SharedPreferences. Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();

   int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
   prefsEdit.putInt("mediaPosition", position);
   prefsEdit.commit();
}
```

For more info read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of onStop() that saves the contents of a draft note to persistent storage:

```
@Override

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Save the note's current draft, because the activity is stopping
    // and we want to be sure the current note progress isn't lost.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE, getCurrentNoteText());
    values.put(NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, getCurrentNoteTitle());

    getContentResolver().update(
            mUri,    // The URI for the note to update.
            values,  // The map of column names and new values to apply to them.
            null,    // No SELECT criteria are used.
            null     // No WHERE columns are used.
            );
}
```

Although the `onPause()` method is called before `onStop()`, you should use `onStop()` to perform larger, more CPU intensive shut-down operations, such as writing information to a database.

from android developer page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Answer (score 0):

You get **(IllegelStateException)** on the **onPause()**.

To resolve this problem you need to put,

```
mp = null;
```

after,

```
mp.stop();
mp.release();
```

because when you check **mp!=null** that time MediaPlayer already release but not **null**.
so, if condition is correct and goto **mp.pause()** but **mp** already release that's why you get error.

Also you need to change name of **MediaPlayer** instance in **onCompletion()**.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
```

because it is used **mp** of onCompletion() for **stop()** and **release()**.
so, change **mp** to **other(like: mp1)**.

check this is helpfull for you.